# Why can I print a dynamically allocated object but not an object created on the stack using cout <<?

Tags: c++, oop, memory

```
class Test{
public:
    Test(int _a){a = _a;}
    int a;
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Test * first = new Test(3);
    cout << "First is " << first << endl;
//Prints the address of the object, obvious
    Test second(5);
    cout << "Second is " << second << endl;
//Compile time error
    return 0;
}
```

It might sound absurd, but why do I get this error while I try to print the second object?

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are
>   'std::basic_ostream' and 'Test')

Comment: Because you're not providing `operator<<` for `Test`.

Comment: In the 1st example `first` is a pointer. In the 2nd example `second` is an object with no `operator<<`

Comment: As drescherjm says, `first` is a pointer: C++ will use generic pointer-printing code to print the address, rather than the `Test` object content/state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `first` is a pointer and you are outputting its numeric value which is a memory address.
2. C++ has no way of knowing what you want by `<< second`.

You need to properly access `a`:

```
// Change
cout << "First is " << first << endl;
cout << "Second is " << second << endl;
// To
cout << "First is " << first->a << endl;
cout << "Second is " << second.a << endl;
```

Look up what `->` vs. `.` means and pointers. If you want to just access the class and have it automatically output the value of `a` then you need to overload the operator:

```
class Test{
public:
    Test(int _a){a = _a;}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t);

    int a;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t)
{
    os << t.a;
    return os;
}
```

One last thing, you dynamically created `first` so be sure to delete it before returning from `main`:

```
int main()
{
   Test * first = new Test(3);
   // Do the rest of your code here.
   delete first;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That overload needs to be a non-member function.

Comment: Just for completeness... the way to print the object that `first` points to - using the custom streaming operator - is to dereference the pointer e.g. `std::cout << *first << '\n';`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the types are different:

```
Test* first      = new Test(3);
Test  second(5);
```

The instance `first` is a pointer type `Test*`.
While `second` is an instance of `Test`.

The standard provides a version of `operator<<` that prints pointers so that explains why `first` is printed.

The second one fails to compile because there is no function declaration (or definition) of: `operator<<(std::ostream&, Test const&)`. You need to define this function for your class (as the standard does not know your class and therefore does not know how to print it).

Usually you define the ouput operator as a friend of the class:

```
class Test{
public:
    Test(int _a){a = _a;}
    int a;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Test const& data)
    {
        return s << " {" << data.a << "} ";
    }
};
```